# How do I show a timestamp member as a date in SQL Server MDX queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx

I have a scenario where I the dimension has a series of date / time members but instead I want to show it grouped to the day, how do I do that?

Example cube query:

```
select {[Measures].[Count]} on columns, 
       [Date].[Date].[Date] on rows
from [Cube]
```

and this query returns:

```
                        | count
2014-03-03 15:50:24.000 |   1
2014-03-03 16:05:10.000 |   1
2014-03-03 16:05:21.000 |   1
2014-03-02 16:30:13.000 |   1
```

I want to be able to show

```
           | count
2014-03-03 |  3
2014-03-02 |  1
```

I'm using Microsoft Analysis Services 2008 R2 and the MDX queries for that

Comment: is time a hierarchy/level in your cube?

Comment: I don't think so, its product that spits out a semi configurable cube structure and when i look at the members they are timestamps. The actual value being passed through is a timestamp. I may ask the vendor if its possible to have it spit out a heirachy. this is about day 3 of me looking at cubes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a little similar to what you're trying to achieve:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[countDays] AS 
    Count((EXISTING [Date].[Calendar].[Date])) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[countDays]} ON COLUMNS
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It returns the following:

[image]